# VXL: Run-Time Check Failure #2

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

With the [VXL library](http://vxl.sourceforge.net/#mail):

I'm using vnl_conjugate_gradient with VC8 (visual studio 2005) and
occasionally I see this error in debug mode:

**Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'z__' was corrupted.**

This is happening while leaving the function cg_ in the file cg.c

This function is literally packed with "goto" btw, could that be the culprit??

Any idea?

PS: Callstack:

- vision.dll!v3p_netlib_cg_(double * x=0x01d6b040, double *
  e=0x0012f1d4, long * it=0x0012f1c8, double * step=0x01d698b8, double *
  t=0x0012f1b8, long * limit=0x01d69868, long * n=0x0012f19c, long *
  m=0x0012f19c, double (double *, void *)* value=0x00f2a9e0, void
  (double *, double *, void *)* grad=0x00f2aae0, void (double *, double
  *, double *, void *)* both=0x00f2abf0, void (double *, double *, void
  *)* pre=0x00f2ad00, double * h__=0x01d6b080, void *
  userdata=0x01d69858, long * error_code=0x0012f190)  Line 1128 + 0xf
  bytes   C
- vision.dll!vnl_conjugate_gradient::minimize(vnl_vector & x={...})  Line 171 + 0x50 bytes        C++

Comment: Any chance of seeing the function ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was due to the cost function returning NAN.